# How did they get to the old watchtower?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Bran's favorite climbing destination was the old broken watchtower. The tower had been struck by lightning, heavily damaged near its top-most part and never rebuilt.

Ok, so Bran knew how to climb all the way up there, however it seemed to me that he was alone in that. In the book it's mentioned that his father had sent people to clean up the tower several times, but they never got all the way to the top.

Quote:

> But no one ever got up to the jagged top of the structure now except for Bran and the crows.

This had me confused, if he was the only one who knew how to get there then how did

> Cersei and Jaime Lannister

manage to get there?

Could they possibly know the secrets of Winterfell better than the Starks? Is it a plot hole? Have I misread something?

Comment: Putting spoiler tags for events that happen in the first chapters/first episodes of a saga isn't really relevant I think

Comment: @Kalissar It is a huge spoiler for the first episode. When I was first watching it, the final scene completely caught me by surprise and that was what made my first impression about the whole series. That surprise wouldn't have been possible if someone just told me what was about to happen.

Comment: The spoiler tag is about who is in the tower, not about what happen. You're right though, I didn't really think of it that way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They weren't on the top of the tower.  They were actually in the First Keep, which was adjacent to the broken tower:

> That brought
>   you up to the blind side of the First Keep, the oldest part of the castle, a squat round fortress that was
>   taller than it looked. Only rats and spiders lived there now but the old stones still made for good climbing.
>   You could go straight up to where the gargoyles leaned out blindly
>    over empty space, and swing from gargoyle to gargoyle, hand over hand, around to the north side. From
>   there, if you really stretched, you could reach out and pull yourself over to the broken tower where it
>   leaned close. ... Bran was moving from gargoyle to gargoyle with the ease of long practice when he heard the voices. He
>   was so startled he almost lost his grip. The First Keep had been empty all his life.

It is also clear that Bran was able to get above the room they were in:

> Bran studied the ledge. He could drop down. It was too narrow to land on, but if he could catch hold as
>   he fell past, pull himself up . . . except that might make a noise, draw them to the window. He was not
>   sure what he was hearing, but he knew it was not meant for his ear

Comment: Gah! You beat me! What @Beofett said.

Comment: @Josh: Ok, I definitely misread it. Thanks to both of you! This makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

In the show they are clearly in the tower instead of the First Keep. However, the show also gives the answer nice and clear, they walked up the steps and entered through a doorway. The door can clearly be seen behind Cersei in the following image.

[image: Cersei in the tower]

Also if you watch the scene below it can clearly be seen that there is a large fireplace in the room so it was used at one time. As such it is likely that it would have been easily accessible even if it is now abandoned. **(WARNING: NSFW parts in the video)**